# Broadcasting intent from BroadcastReceiver to Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have registered a BroadcastReceiver in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".OrderReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<category android:name="com.gndp" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and in OrderReceiver class I'm trying to broadcast a received intent this way:

```
public class OrderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent) {
                 if(intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
                 intent.setAction("com.gndp.device.REGISTERED");
                 mContext.sendBroadcast(intent); //BAZINGA
             }

}
```

This broadcasted intent(BAZINGA) is received in this class(OrderReceiver) but not in another activity where i want to receive it. Here's the activity:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    private BroadcastReceiver deviceRegisteredBroadcastReciever;
    @Override
    onCreate(){
        ...
        deviceRegisteredBroadcastReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                             //broadcast never reach here<----PROBLEM
                             }
    }

    @Override
    onResume() {
        ...
        LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext);
        lbm.registerReceiver(deviceRegisteredBroadcastReciever, new IntentFilter("com.gndp.device.REGISTERED"));
    }

}
```

Have tried a lot of things including sending broadcast by instance of LocalBroadcastManager, using an inner class instead of BroadcastReceiver in the activity.

RegisterActivity is in foreground when OrderReceiver receives its first broadcast and it stays in foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send a global broadcast in the OrderReceiver by calling **sendBroadcast** of **Context** class and trying to receive this with **LocalBroadcastManager**.

You should either broadcast with **LocalBroadcastManager** or register ordinary **BroadcastReceiver** with **Activity.registerReceiver** method in the **RegisterActivity**.